# Resolver Emitting Error ` ERROR Error: "[object Object]" `

Tags: angular, angular-resolver

I'm having a problem with regards of implementing a resolver on my routes as it has no issue until I include `InitialDataResolver` on my routing module.

> pages-routing.module.ts

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { FrontComponent } from '../layouts/front/front.component';
import { HomeComponent } from './home/home.component';
import { DocsComponent } from './docs/docs.component';
import { InitialDataResolver } from './../shared/resolvers/initial-data.resolver';

const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    component: FrontComponent,
    children: [
      { path: '', component: HomeComponent },
      { path: 'docs', component: DocsComponent }
    ],
    resolve: {
      init: InitialDataResolver
    },
  }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [ RouterModule.forChild(routes) ],
  exports: [ RouterModule ],
  providers: [ InitialDataResolver ]
})
export class PagesRoutingModule { }
```

> initial-data.resolver.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { ActivatedRouteSnapshot, Resolve, RouterStateSnapshot } from '@angular/router';
import { Observer } from 'rxjs/Observer';
import { AppInitService } from '../services/app-init.service';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';

@Injectable()
export class InitialDataResolver implements Resolve<any> {

  constructor(private appInitService: AppInitService) {}

  resolve(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot,
          state: RouterStateSnapshot): Observable<any> {
    return Observable.create((observer: Observer<any>) => {

      this.appInitService.init()
          .subscribe(data => {
            this.appInitService.preload();
            observer.next(data);
            observer.complete();
          });

    });
  }

}
```

The error that I'm encountering is `ERROR Error: "[object Object]"`. see the snapshot below: 
[image: object Object Error]

Answer (score 118, accepted):

This lack of detailed error occurred when using `Mozilla Firefox`. so what you need to do is to switch over to `Google Chrome` to see the specific error.

**UPDATED:**

You can also Store the error as Global Variable

[image]

then you can type `temp0.message` to see the actual error message

[image]

[image]

Comment: This is ridiculous. Didn't expect that at all. Thank you for your answer. Solved my issue.

Comment: Wow. Last thing I was expecting as well. Thank you.

Comment: @zero01alpha Your welcome mate :) I hope Mozilla fix this in the future

Comment: I hope Angular make their framework work better on Mozilla

Comment: Funny thing is I have the error only on Firefox, Chrome works fine. How to debug this? :head-on-wall:

Comment: This should not be the accepted answer. Saying "use a different browser" absolves companies and authors of ensuring their code works properly and promotes a browser mono-culture.

Comment: @LocalPCGuy I think for debugging an error which is not visible on a specific browser then It is logical to switch for just few seconds since as a web developer we switch browsers every now and then to check if the code is working on all browsers. in this case its only an error that is not visible on Mozilla so it should be fine. anyways I updated my answer.

Comment: While I do agree that as web developers, we should have different browsers installed, and it isn't that hard to check, I pretty strongly disagree that this is a non-issue. It shouldn't be on the end developers to switch browsers to see if there are different error messages depending on the browser. Firefox/Mozilla is still a main-stream browser and as such, it should be tested against.

Answer (score 22):

In console you can store errors like

> ERROR Error: "[object Object]"

as global variable

[image]

and then get error message from object `temp0.message`

Comment: What a lifesaving answer! Thank you

Comment: Bless you. This is indeed a lifesaver.

Answer (score 4):

I have found solution for detailed error working in firefox. Its based on defining custom error handler and inspecting error properties yourself.
After these steps, the errors were displayed properly, no need to switch to chrome.

1. Define custom error handler class:

```js
import { ErrorHandler } from '@angular/core'

export class MyErrorHandler implements ErrorHandler {

    handleError(error: any) {
        // console.error(Object.getOwnPropertyNames(error))
        // Object.getOwnPropertyNames(error).forEach(p => console.error(error[p]))
        console.error(error.fileName, error.lineNumber, ':', error.columnNumber, '\n', error.message, error.rejection)
    }

}
```

2. Then register it as provider in main component

```js
@NgModule({
    declarations: []
    imports: []
    providers: [{provide: ErrorHandler, useClass: MyErrorHandler}], // <-- register MyErrorHandler
    bootstrap: [RootComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
resolve(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot,
      state: RouterStateSnapshot): Observable<any> {
    return Observable.create((observer: Observer<any>) => {

      this.appInitService.init()
          .subscribe(data => {
            this.appInitService.preload();
            observer.next(data);
            observer.complete();
          });

    }).map(item => !!item)
}
```

The code above will work for you.

if your rxjs version is 6.x you will use `.pipe(map(item => !!item))`

Comment: Why? Could you please provide an explanation or link or any justification.

Answer (score 0):

This error comes due to wrong router declaration. Also exact error never going to come in Firefox. Check route file in chrome. #angularjs-route

Answer (score 0):

The error could hide details on firefox if you build without --prod and host in web server, try to build with --prod if you are hosting on a web server to get details about the error.

Answer (score 0):

one-time solution :
find function defaultErrorLogger in dist/vendor.bundle.js and add:

```
for (var _i = 1; _i < arguments.length; _i++) {
    values[_i - 1] = arguments[_i];
}
console.log(arguments);
console.error.apply(console, values); code here
```

then refresh page without recompiling

Answer (score 0):

Mainly this error is found when using database object from '@angular/fire'

this can be fixed by using `this.db.object('/' + ....).subscribe(...)`