# How to debug Angular in Firefox properly - Error: "[object Object]"

Tags: angular, firefox

Is there any way to enable the same level of debugging that Google Chrome gives out of the box for debugging Angular applications and in particular to avoid errors like that:

```
Error: "[object Object]"
```

I'm using **FF 68.0b2 (64-bit - dev edition)**. The same error in Chrome is human readable:

```
core.js:15724 
ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: 
Cannot read property 'unsubscribe' of undefined
TypeError: Cannot read property 'unsubscribe' of undefined
    at ProfileComponent.push......
```

I'm currently using Angular v7.2.15.

[EDIT]

**Code Example**

```
ngOnInit() {
  this.authSub = this.authService.isAuthenticated()
      .subscribe((authenticated: boolean) => {...}

  this.profileSub = this.userService.getCurrentUserProfile()
            .subscribe((me) => {...}

}

ngOnDestroy() {
  this.authSub.unsubscribe();
  this.profileSub.unsubscribe();
}
```

Reference: http://codedam.com/angular-error-error-object-object/

Comment: Provide some code please @sentenza

Comment: Can you check if you are not console logging the `Error: "[object Object]"` in your code ?

Comment: @Aarsh I added the code example. @ibenjelloun I'm not logging to the console. It's an error that comes out from `core.js` itself.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Resolver Emitting Error \` ERROR Error: "\[object Object\]" \`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51041301/resolver-emitting-error-error-error-object-object)

Answer (score 0):

I think problem in Angular `defaultErrorLogger(console)`
So I get error message as described here  https://stackoverflow.com/a/56440176/6190470